# 2-wire vs. 3-wire watt-hour meter?

Tags: electricity, meter

A kWh meter (electromechanical induction meter) is installed in front of each room in our apartment to measure the electricity usage of each room. Each room has its own breaker box to set up the 110-V (hot wire & neutral) and 220-V (two hot wires) electricity. Before the breaker box is a single-phase 2-wire meter with two hot wires going in (from the 220-V city electricity) and out (to the breaker box). The city electricity neutral line is connected directly to the ground bar in the breaker box without passing the meter.

[image]

My question is: how does the meter measure the current when a 110-V home appliance is using the electricity? Since the current would alternate between a hot wire and the neutral wire, the other hot wire would be left unused.

Can a 2-wire 220-V meter measure the kWh value correctly when a 110-V home appliance is running? Should we replace it with a 3-wire meter?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean ground (sounds incorrect) or do you mean neutral?

Comment: I believe that it may be possible to properly meter kWh on a split-phase system using only the two hot lines, but the only way to tell if the meters that you have will do that is to consult the instruction or other literature for those meters.

Comment: Yes, neutral is the correct way to call it. But since the neutral wire is usually screwed into a ground bar in a breaker box, so people in our country also call it "ground".

Comment: @CharlesCowie For a meter that uses only the two hot lines to measure 110-V appliances correctly, I guess some extra design and components are needed, but a 2-wire meter generally costs less than a 3-wire one. Therefore, my intuition tells me that 220-V 2-wire meters on the market are not supposed to be used on 110-V appliances.

Some netizens claim that a 2-wire meter will give a higher reading than a 3-wire one when working on the same 110-V appliance, but I've never seen a detailed explanation or experimental data.

Comment: You could generate your own experimental data, turn everything off on one meter, connect a known 110 V load and see what the meter counts.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in my mind. After searching some technical documents on internet, I found the information provided by the following links might be more reasonable.

https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2012/11/how-to-wire-single-phase-kwh-meter.html

In short, there are many versatile designs of Watt-Hour meter which can be configured (through wiring the meter) to be used in various situation. (2-wire or 3-wire)

Answer (score -1):

You need a 3 wire power meter to measure power in both split phases combined.